# Installing BeautifulSoup4 with Pip

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I am trying to install beatifulsoup4 with pip but running into issues.

I have python3.6 but it didn't come with pip, so i installed it using

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

however, when I tried to install beautiful soup4 by typing

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I got this:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I couldn't figure out how to update permissions and I wasn't sure if installing it to another place would cause path errors (I'm new to this!) so I used

```
python -m pip install --user beautifulsoup4
```

and it returned the following:

```
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/d/10f46e5cfac773e22707237bfcd51bbffeaf0a576b0a847ec7ab15bd7ace  /beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (86kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

so that's exactly what i did, I typed in 'pip install --upgrade pip' and this was returned:

```
 equirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg (10.0.1)
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
```

Although I thought it was weird, I ignored it and went ahead to confirm I had installed beautifulsoup4 using pip list. It wasn't in the list, so I used pip show beautifulsoup4 and nothing was even returned.

I'm not sure what I should do at this point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions of Python do `pip` and `python -m pip` use?  You can test by running `pip --version` and `python -m pip --version`.

Comment: @jwodder ` pip --version`  returned  `pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)`  and  `python -m pip --version` returned `pip 9.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6) `

Comment: There's your problem, then; you keep switching between two different versions of pip for two different versions of Python.

Comment: @jwodder how would I fix this? I'm not sure how it even happened. Also, is that also the reason why beautifulsoup isn't showing up and why it's saying I don't have permissions?

Comment: You fix it by deciding what version of Python you want to use pip with and then consistently using the pip for that version.  The permissions issue is unrelated.

Comment: @jwodder sorry for so many questions but how do I do that? by specifying which version of python I want to use in every command? If so, is that done by simply including the version like 'pip10.0.1 install beautifulsoup4' ? or is there a way to set python3.6 to use pip10.0.1?  Again, my apologies for being so ignorant but I wasn't able to find any help in previous posts and other forums